# Most universal sequence of keyboard presses to start an editor

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, arduino

I have a very compact Arduino with integrated USB connector, the [CJMCU Beetle](http://www.dx.com/p/cjmcu-beetle-leonardo-usb-atmega32u4-mini-development-board-for-arduino-black-384544) that can emulate a virtual USB keyboard.

[image: CJMCU Beetle]

I would like to configure it to send keystrokes to any computer it is connected to, with the goal of opening any kind of text editor or text window, and to input some hardcoded text like telephone number, email address, ways of contacting me. The goal is to attach it to a keychain.

The sequence of keystrokes should be as compatible as possible, so that it would work on Windows (7, 8.x, 10) and OS X (>10.8).

**Edit**

If no such universal sequence of keystrokes exists, what sequences could I use, one after the other, to cover the various operating systems? the sequence meant for an operating system should not cause issues on the other ones.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  This question seems out of scope to be honest.

Comment: I wondered if there is a universal way of clearly displaying some text by using only a virtual keyboard. I will clarify the question.

Comment: What does a virtual keyboard have to emulating a USB keyboard which is what you would need to do.

Comment: I know I have to emulate a USB keyboard, I wondered if there was a way to find a sequence of keystrokes that would work everywhere.

Comment: Keyboard signals are keyboard signals.  You would have to write drivers for the emulated driver specific to each platform.  Once you did that how you send a keystroke would be nearly identical across the platforms.  What  you want to send is platform independent, in fact, its machine specific since not all installations have the same applications.

Comment: @OlafM have you heard of the USB Rubber Ducky?  With some [custom firmware](https://github.com/DavidSkrundz/ducky-decode/blob/master/Firmware/Composite_Duck_4cap.hex), It supports modifier keys.  For instance it will run the keystroke sequence one way if you have the caps lock key press, or num lock, or scroll lock.  [Check it out](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe?variant=353378649)

Comment: @JesseWallace Unfortunately this Arduino has no ARM chip, I cannot use the sources of that project. The idea is good. Since I know of libraries to emulate a keyboard, and given the lack of SD, I will simply hardcode the keypresses.

Comment: @OlafM That was not necessarily my idea.  I was saying if you wanted to get something that does exactly what you want, is open source, and supports custom firmware, then you should buy one.  Got mine for around $40 from hakshop.com.  It is based on a [teensy](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as universal keyboard shortcut to open a text editor. Neither in Windows, nor in OS X, nor in Linux Gnome or KDE. So you are out of luck there.

However, you can use these shortcut chains:

**Windows**:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Gnome (Linux)**:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**OS X**:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>

OS X here is the most difficult case, since there is no standard shorcut for Terminal, and what I suggest is to use Spotlight (indexing service) shortcut, which may be a bit slow to find TextEdit (default text editor). However, on most modern machines it is being found instantaneously.

Comment: I modified the question asking for multiple sequences, one per operating system, but where each one of them does not cause issues on the OSes where it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Well, here you go.